# A simple start button in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

Im making my first 2D game in unity and I have successfully made it. However I want a start button.I have looked up videos on how to make a start button and they all seem to have a start button on a different screen and once clicked it goes to another scene. Where as I would like my button to be on the same screen as my game and once clicked it starts the game, while having the button disappear. Can the code also be in c# thank you.

Comment: You could [pause the game](https://answers.unity.com/questions/630303/how-to-pause-and-resume-the-game.html) until started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to have different scenes (which, by the way, it's the recommended pattern) you can pause the game until the player presses the button. More informations can be found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html).

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

class GameManager: MonoBehaviour
{
   public Button startButton;

   private void Awake()
   {
       Time.timeScale = 0f;
   }

   private void OnEnable()
   {
      startButton.onClick.AddListener(StartGame);
   }

   private void OnDisable()
   {
      startButton.onClick.RemoveListener(StartGame);
   }

   private void StartGame()
   {
      Time.timeScale = 1f;

      // Hides the button
      startButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your button on your main scene that's it.